# how to use this c++ template function. simple beginner question

Tags: c++

I found this merge sort function but i dont know how to use it.
please help

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename Comparable>
void mergeSort(vector<Comparable*> &v)
{
    mergeSortPart(v, 0, v.size() - 1);
}

template <typename Comparable>
void mergeSortPart(vector<Comparable*> &v,int first,int last)
{  
    if(first < last)
    {
        int mid = (first + last)/2;
        mergeSortPart(v, first, mid);
        mergeSortPart(v, mid + 1, last);
        merge(v, first, mid, last);
    }
}
template <typename Comparable>
void merge(vector<Comparable*> &v, int first, int mid,int last)
{
    vector<Comparable*> temp(v.size());
    int first1 = first; int last1 = mid; int first2 = mid + 1;
    int last2 = last; int index = first1;
    while((first1 <= last1) && (first2 <= last2))
    {
        if(*v[first1]<*v[first2])
            temp[index++] = v[first1++];
        else
            temp[index++] = v[first2++];
    }
    while(first1 <= last1)
        temp[index++] = v[first1++];
    while(first2 <= last2)
        temp[index++] = v[first2++];
    for(index = first; index <= last; index++)
        v[index] = temp[index];
}

void main()
{  
    vector<int> arr (20);
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        arr[i]=i;
    mergeSort<int>(arr);
}
```

In `main` function i tried to declare an array of 6 elements and called `mergeSort` template function but it gives a compilation error:

> Error  1   error C2664: `'mergeSort'` : cannot convert parameter 1 from `'std::vector<_Ty>'` to `'std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &'`

I am not very familiar with template functions so if some one could show me how to use this function that would be a treat to me

Thanks

Comment: If this is homework, you should tag it as such.

Comment: and if it isn't take a look at [std::stable_sort()](http://en.literateprograms.org/Merge_sort_(C_Plus_Plus))

Comment: When dealing with template errors, it is important to read the whole error message. In particular, it probably contained what `_Ty` and `_Ax` were in that particular instantiation.

Comment: hi.. i dont know much of c++, pls tell me how to use this function.
vector<int *> arr (20);
 for(int i=0;i<20;i++) 
    *arr[i]=i; 
mergeSort<int>(arr);

i tried adding pointer but it still throws runtime exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the parameter to `mergeSort` is `vector<Comparable*>`, it can only sort vectors of pointers, and not vectors of ints or other objects.

Comment: Here `Comparable` is a template parameter, so is just any type. The problem is that function is specified as taking a vector of `Comparable*`, not `Comparable`. This means that the actual parameter must be a vector of pointers to the objects that should be sorted.

Comment: sorry for being such a noob. but i really am brand new to c++ and couldn't get my head around this one. when i search for vectors or templates in c++ i get info on them individually but there aren't much tutorials which are combining these both.

Comment: I learned this a long time ago, so don't know any current tutorials. This mergeSort example seems **very** specialized, so it is perhaps not a good point to start. If you want to sort a vector of ints, or other objects that and not pointers, you have std::sort and std::stable_sort for that.

Comment: yaa.. this one really seems different. 

 vector<int *> arr (10);
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  *arr[i]=i;
 mergeSort<int>(arr);


i tried like this and this did not throw any compiler error but is throwing runtime exception. 

pls tell me how to get around this one.

Comment: to my application i cant use built in sort functions such as std::sort or std::stable_sort. that is why i started looking for this function. i was told that this is perfect for my requirement so please tell me how to use this one...

Comment: Looks like homework. Are you supposed to write you own sort? Then this will not work. This code is used to sort a kind of index, where the vector contains pointers to objects stored elsewhere. only the index is sorted, not the objects themselves. Rather specialized. Your snippet two comments up doesn't work, because it only has the pointers and no real objects being pointed to.

Comment: @Bo Persson: please tell me how to use this function

Comment: I though I did. :-)  You first have to create some objects somewhere, perhaps in another vector or a different container. You then create your "index" vector with pointers to the original objects. The `mergeSort` can then sort this "index" so that the pointers point to the original objects in the sort order. The objects themselves are not sorted, just the "index".

Comment: hmm.. let me try that out.. i'll get back to you with result.

Comment: @Bo Persson: IT WORKED!!!!!... I cant thank you enough for this help.. thank you soooo much. 

void main()
{
 int iarr[]={9,10,2,3,7,5,6,4,1,0};
 vector<int> arr(10);
 vector<int *> parr(10);
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  arr[i]=iarr[i];
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  parr[i] = &arr[i];

 cout<<endl;
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  cout<<" "<<*parr[i];

 mergeSort<int>(parr);

 cout<<endl;
 cout<<endl;
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  cout<<" "<<*parr[i];
}

Comment: @user743677 - The convention here is to say thank you by clicking on the checkmark to the left of your favorite answer. The mark turns solid green so everyone can see your selection (and also gives me some points that I don't really need :-).

Answer (score 0):

You left out the most pertinent part of the error message: the respective types of `_Ty`, which in one case would be `int` and in the other `int*`.

`template<typename Comparable> mergeSort` takes a `vector<Comparable*>&` argument.

You're explicitly specifying `int` for `Comparable` and passing a `vector<int>`, whereas it would want a `vector<int*>`.

Comment: hi ildjarn, i am quiet new to c++ could you show the right way to use it please.

Comment: ok.. i tried this  vector<int *> arr (20);
 for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
  *arr[i]=i;
 mergeSort<int>(arr); but its still doesn't work